# Django serializer with a filed that has a OneToOne relationship

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-auth

In my project I have two 'types' of users: Customers and Businesses. They are an extension of the django base User from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

I have in my `models.py`:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Business(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='business', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    cf = models.CharField(max_length=16, validators=[ssn_validation])
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
```

Ok, then I have two different registration, one for Customers and one for Businesses.
A problem is that, to validate the password, sent from a REST API, I need to compare `password` with `password2`, create a User (django base), and pass it to my Customer.objects.create, like:

I have in my `serializers.py`:

```
class CustomerRegistationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username',
                                     validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email',
                                  validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password', write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_style': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    birth_date = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'birth_date', 'phone']

    def save(self):
        username = self.validated_data['user']['username']
        password = self.validated_data['user']['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        email = self.validated_data['user']['email']
        first_name = self.validated_data['user']['first_name']
        last_name = self.validated_data['user']['last_name']
        phone = self.validated_data['phone']

        try:
            birth_date = self.validated_data['birth_date']
        except KeyError:
            birth_date = None

         if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match!'})

        user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()

        customer = Customer.objects.create(user=user,
                                           birth_date=birth_date,
                                           phone=phone)
        return customer
```

That's actually working, but in case of errors can happen that a User is created, but a Customer not.
Is there a cleaner way to make Customers registration, always checking for `password == password2`?

**EDIT:** I found a more elegant way to handle this:

@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    password = self.validated_data['user']['password']
    password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

```
user = User.objects.create(**self.validated_data['user'])

if password != password2:
    raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match!'})
user.set_password(password)
user.is_active = False
user.save()
update_last_login(None, user)

del self.validated_data['user']
del self.validated_data['password2']

customer = Customer.objects.create(user=user, **self.validated_data)
return customer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to require that all of the DB transactions you are making during `save()` method are successful to effectively write it on DB, and not to write anything if there is an error at any point in the process, you are typically asking for **atomicity** (one of the four ACID capabilities of a Database)

Use this Django decorator, typically made for this:

```
from django.db import transaction

    @transaction.atomic    
    def save(self):
        <...>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you